# How to hash an unbounded array of unbounded strings to a digest of N integers with no zeroes

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, hash

I am trying to design the following algorithm

> Input: unbounded array of unbounded strings sorted alphabetically, integer N
>
> Output: Hex integer ID with N digits, none of which are zero

I'm not sure how to create good hash functions. So far my best attempt has been to

- take each character in a string, multiply it by a prime (of a list of primes that eventually loops back)
- multiply each obtained number together and `xor` it with a pseudo-random bit string of length **N/4**.
- create the `final_id` as the `first_id`
- For each string id generated this way, `xor` the `final_id` with this string id

Or in pseudo code:

```
int ids[] = {};
for(string str : strings)
{
     int id = 1;
     for(char c: str)
     {
        id *= c * list.nextPrime(); 
     }
    id ^ hash1;
    ids.push_back(id);
}

final_id = ids[0];
for(id : ids) final_id = (final_id * id) ^ hash2;

return final_id;
```

This seems random enough for a good choice of primes and hashes, but it does not guarantee non-zero digits.

I also have the issue that I don't know if I can make this uniformly distributed (to minimize hash collisions).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take an ordinary hash, write it out base 15, and then increment every digit.

Comment: If you just need a hash function for use in something like a hash table, you could polynomial hash all the strings and then polynomial hash the hashes.

Comment: @Alexander Zhang it's not for a hash table, it's to create a unique id. Similar but not exactly the same

Comment: "hash" and "unique id" are fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: No they aren't, given a set S such that |S| << N you can create |S| unique ids through a hash function. Remember that in case of collision you just rehash, ultimately if you select your parameters right, you will get unique ids.

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing. You want hashes such that different values have a low probability of having the same hash, while you don't need it to be cryptographically secure, which is pretty much what a hash table needs.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Sorry, I was not replyong to you, that last comment was in repsonse to JimMischel's comment ""hash" and "unique id" are fundamentally incompatible"

Comment: @Makogan The OP's question says that he wants to represent an unbounded array of unbounded strings as a finite array of (I assume 32-bit) integers. By definition, that's going to violate the pigeonhole principle. And, yes, if |S| is much smaller than the hash code range, then you can rehash. But the OP hasn't said how many strings he has. I took "unbounded" to mean ... "unbounded."

Comment: Do you really need to *generate* a unique id? Or can you simply *assign* a unique id? Is there any need, at some point in the future, to examine an array of strings to determine what its unique key is?

Comment: @Makogan I was replying to the OP.